# How can I disable this in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Sorry, but i don't know the correct name for this...

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Android Studio Preferences, go to Editor > General > Appearance and untick **Show breadcrumbs**